# Override custom module adminhtml block

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, override-block

im working on Magento 1.9.3
i'm trying to override the admin grid of a custom module.
The original module strucutre is:

```
Miravist
- Helpdesk
-- Block
--- Adminhtml
---- Ticket
----- Grid.php
```

original module config.xml

```
<blocks>
  <helpdesk>
    <class>Mirasvit_Helpdesk_Block</class>
  </helpdesk>
</blocks>
```

my module config.xml is

```
...
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helpdesk>
                <rewrite>
                    <adminhtml_ticket_grid>MyCompany_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid</adminhtml_ticket_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </helpdesk>
        </blocks>
...
```

For what i've found around it should works but it does not.
Any help?

--**EDIT**--
what i'm trying to do is override `protected function _prepareColumns()` maybe is it the problem?

Comment: Verify that your file is in app/code/local/Mycompany/Helpdesk/Block/Adminhtml/Ticket/Grid.php.  Can you paste the original module's config.xml blocks section?

Comment: @seanbreeden, thanks for answer, the path of my file is right. I've edited the question and added the original module block part of cong.xml

Comment: That looks like it should work. Make sure your namespace in your Grid.php is `class MyCompany_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid extends Mirasvit_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid`. Be sure to flush caches.

Comment: Another thing to check is that your module is activate in app/etc/modules. Sometimes it's easy to overlook the simple things.

Comment: @seanbreeden everything you suggest is as it should be. thats why i can't understand why doesn't work.

Comment: Is your module showing up under Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced?

Comment: @seanbreeden yes, it's override other parts too. it does not work just for the admin grid.

Comment: Try to add <depends>  <Mirasvit_Helpdesk /> </depends> in your MyCompany_Helpdesk.xml ... maybe it's a priority issue and your custom module is loaded before mirasvit module

Comment: @AlexConstantinescu it has already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have changed

```
MyCompany_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid extends Mirasvit_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid
```

with

```
MyCompany_Helpdesk_Block_Adminhtml_Ticket_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
```

and now it works.

But in this way i had to override the whole class non just the `protected function _prepareColumns()`